# My cost function behaves unexpectedly while training my machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I've recently started the Coursera ML course and took It upon my self to train a linear regression model through gradient descent using python. Here's the code I came up with:

```
import csv

# hypothesis function
def h(row, a, b, c, d, e, f):
     return a + (b * row[0]) + (c * row[1]) + (d * row[2]) + (e * row[3]) + (f * row[4])

# cost function
def costFunc(X, Y, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5):
    s = 0
    for rowX, y in zip(X, Y):
        s += (h(rowX, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5) - y) ** 2
    return s / (2 * len(Y))


# loading the data
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    X, Y = [], []
    for row in data:
        X.append(list(map(float, row[:len(row) - 2])))
        Y.append(float(row[len(row) - 1]))


# number of training examples
m = len(X)


# computing the mean and std_deviation for each feature
x1_mean, x1_std = sum([row[0] for row in X]) / len(X), max([row[0] for row in X]) - min([row[0] for row in X])
x2_mean, x2_std = sum([row[1] for row in X]) / len(X), max([row[1] for row in X]) - min([row[1] for row in X])
x3_mean, x3_std = sum([row[2] for row in X]) / len(X), max([row[2] for row in X]) - min([row[2] for row in X])
x4_mean, x4_std = sum([row[3] for row in X]) / len(X), max([row[3] for row in X]) - min([row[3] for row in X])
x5_mean, x5_std = sum([row[4] for row in X]) / len(X), max([row[4] for row in X]) - min([row[4] for row in X])


# scaling the features
for row in X:
    row[0] = (row[0] - x1_mean) / x1_std
    row[1] = (row[1] - x2_mean) / x2_std
    row[2] = (row[2] - x3_mean) / x3_std
    row[3] = (row[3] - x4_mean) / x4_std
    row[4] = (row[4] - x5_mean) / x5_std


# defining the starting values for gradient descent
theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5 = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
alpha = 1
convergence = 0.1


# initializing the convergence condition
convergent = False

# computing the values of theta through gradient descent
while not convergent:

    temp0, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    for row, y in zip(X, Y):
        temp0 += h(row, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5) - y
        temp1 += (h(row, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5) - y) * row[0]
        temp2 += (h(row, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5) - y) * row[1]
        temp3 += (h(row, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5) - y) * row[2]
        temp4 += (h(row, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5) - y) * row[3]
        temp5 += (h(row, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5) - y) * row[4]
    temp0, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5 = temp0/m, temp1/m, temp2/m, temp3/m, temp4/m, temp5/m

    # updating the values of theta
    theta0 = theta0 - alpha * temp0
    theta1 = theta1 - alpha * temp1
    theta2 = theta2 - alpha * temp2
    theta3 = theta3 - alpha * temp3
    theta4 = theta4 - alpha * temp4
    theta5 = theta5 - alpha * temp5

    # computing the value of the cost function and printing it
    cost = costFunc(X, Y, theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5)
    print(cost)

    # evaluation whether the cost function has converged
    if cost <= convergence:
        convergent = True

print("Done Training!")
print('theta0 = ', theta0)
print('theta1 = ', theta1)
print('theta2 = ', theta2)
print('theta3 = ', theta3)
print('theta4 = ', theta4)
print('theta5 = ', theta5)
```

My problem is, no matter what value I use for alpha, the value of the cost function decreases really slowly and stays stuck around the 38.5... mark, and for some value it even stays the same and doesn't change every iteration, so the problem probably stems from my code, but I can't figure out what I did wrong.

The dataset has 5 features and 414 examples.

Comment: To start with, Instead of doing an add and multiply for each variable in your data I would suggest to use Numpy to do matrix/vector multiplications, thereby simplifying your code. Here's a simple tutorial: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/post/linear_regression/

Comment: @Bar I actually wanted to do this by hand and see if It works. The course uses matlab/octave so I'll be using those when working with matrices, but for now, I wanted to implement something of my own. Can you see any problems in my code?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your data loading : 
`X.append(list(map(float, row[:len(row) - 2])))` should be `X.append(list(map(float, row[:len(row) - 1])))`, otherwise you never use the last feature. Since it's a constant in your implementation, that could explain why your cost function never decrease. Can you test that ?

Comment: @CoMartel Wouldn't that just return the last element of the data, which is the label for that example? Python indexing starts at zero which means the last element resides at index n-1 where n is the length of the row right?

Comment: numpy slicing is [included : excluded], e.g range(5) [:-1] would be [0,1,2,3] and [:-2] (like in your case) would be [0,1,2].